# Associative Arrays - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate an associative array, in a dynamic way. I have been reading a lot of documents but unable to figure out the right way.

The outcome of the code will be

```
op{
    '0': value1, value2
    '128': value3, value4, value 6
    '630': value7
}
```

This is what i have written and is not working

```
var arr =  [];
for(var i = 1; i <=last ; i++){
    var key = rec[i].op;
    var op = {};
    op[key] = rec[i].description;
    arr.push(op);
}
```

The most recent record is overwriting the previous record.

Comment: There are a lot of variables in your code that aren't declared. Did you post all your relevant code?
Also, the desired outcome isn't a valid object. are those arrays containing multiple `valueX`'s?

Comment: FYI, JS doesn't have associative arrays; they have objects. A lot of people make that mistake.

Comment: Yes they are arrays containing multiple values. The outcome will be an object containing multiple arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
var op = {};
for(var i = 0; i < last ; i++)
{
    var key = rec[i].op;
    if (op[key] == undefined) 
    {
        op[key] = [];
    }
    op[key].push(rec[i].description);
}
```